# CXF RestFul Service - Get Post Body Parameters

Tags: web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I have developed a webservice following the below link, however I am unable to get the request parameters from the POST request body.

http://info.appdirect.com/blog/how-to-easily-build-rest-web-services-with-java-spring-and-apache-cxf

I use the Soap UI to invoke the
service, with "Post QueryString in Message Body" option checked. 
So far, I have tried below options, but none seem to work:

- Tried **MultiValued Map**, but the map is always empty.

  ```
  @POST
  @Path("/getpostfile/{fileName}")
  @Produces("application/pdf")
  @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  public Response getPostFile(MultivaluedMap form){...}
  ```
- Tried **@FormParam()** & **@QueryParam** as well, but still the params are null in webservice method.
- Tried creating a POJO bean with **@XmlRootElement** annotation, however this time I get an exception saying **"SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class com.wcc.LoginInfo, ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**. LoginInfo is my bean class with two parameters:

  ```
  @XmlRootElement
  public class LoginInfo {
      String username;
      String password;
      ....
  ```

Below is the service method:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/getpostfile/{fileName}")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public Response getPostFile(LoginInfo logininfo){...}
```

Below is my cxf-beans.xml file:

```
    <bean .....>
    <jaxrs:server id="wccservice" address="/">
       <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
           <ref bean="wccdocumentservice" />
       </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
       <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="formUrlEncodeProvider" />
       </jaxrs:providers>
 </jaxrs:server>


 <bean id="wccdocumentservice" class="com.wcc.WCCDocumentServiceImpl" />
 <bean id="formUrlEncodeProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider" />
 <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
    <property name="marshallAsJaxbElement" value="true" />
 </bean>
```

Any ideas on how to retrieve the POST parameters in request body, in the Webservice method?

Comment: I have the same question too.. did you find something?

Answer (score 2):

Guess I was dwelling too much into CXF, missed the simple approach. We can get the Post request parameters in CXF service similar to the way we get the parameters in a Servlet.

For Query Parameters in POST request:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/getpostfile/{fileName}")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public Response getPostFile(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName, @Context HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
     System.out.println("id is : " + request.getParameter("id")+", password is : " + request.getParameter("password"));
```

and for Parameters in POST message body, you may use **getBody()** method from below link:

[Getting request payload from POST request in Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet)

Hope that helps someone!