# Why is the request object in my jsp empty after posting FormData?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("htmlContent", strHTML);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = 'blob';
request.open("POST", "emxRenderPDFFop.jsp");
request.send(formData, true);
```

In my jsp,

```
request.getParameter("htmlContent");
```

is null. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: May be i need more information

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet

Comment: The problem is that you are sending payload, so you can't read `htmlContent` POST parameter.

Comment: Or you can try `request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` after `open`.