# Getting a 411 Length Required error when parameters are very long

Tags: java, angularjs, google-app-engine

I am executing a POST request with Angular JS against a Java servlet running on Google App Engine. The code works fine, unfortunately I've noticed that if one (or more) parameters are very long I get the following error:

> Error: Length Required
>
> POST requests require a Content-length header.

This is my Angular JS code:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function($scope,$http,$log) {

this.myfunction = function() {

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/myservlet',
    params: { method: 'my_method', param1 : $("#param1").val(), param 2: ... }
}).success(function(data) {
                
}).error(function(data) {
                
});

};
}
```

Param1, param2 etc are different fields, mostly textarea though. Any suggestion? Honestly I don't know what to do.

EDIT: I tried setting the Content-Length in the header myself but I get an error as I expected...

```
headers : { 'Content-Length' : 0 },
```

> Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"

So basically, if I set the Content-Length the browser refuses to execute the call, if I don't set it then the server says it's required... What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` argument you are using is used to pass GET variables **as part of the url** even when `method` is POST ([$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)). To pass information in the body of the POST request you have to use the `data` argument.

So, your request should be:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/myservlet',
    data: { method: 'my_method', param1 : $("#param1").val(), param 2: ... }
}).success(function(data) {

}).error(function(data) {

});
```

Comment: That way on servlet side request.getParameter("method") returns null :(

Comment: Just a sec, gonna look at how java eats this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet they say here that you need to use `getReader()` to read the body of the request

Comment: I dont want to change my existing code server side, is there any way to set the content-length and/or keep using request,getParameter? Thank you.

Comment: Not that I'm familiar with. Sorry