# Fetch in ReactNative can not deliver the paras in body to the server

Tags: post, react-native, fetch

ReactNative provide me with fetch to send a httpRequest.The attribute of body includes my parameters which are to send to the server.But I can't get the parameters on my server.My codes are here:

```
fetch(`${keys.api}/login`, 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password,
            }),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }, 

        }
    ).then((response) => {
        if(response._bodyText == 'success') {
            this.props.resetToRoute({
                name: '主页',
                component: Main,
                hideNavigationBar: true,
            });
        } else {
            this.cancelLogin();
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
        this.cancelLogin();
    });
```

And the console in my J2EE Web Server prints the message:
[The httpRequest message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE79w.png)

There is no parameter in my httpRequest（In other words,The body can not deliver any parameters）,I need help.
It's dangerous to show my username and password in the url.

Answer (score -1):

i have met the problem twice on jetty-8.1 on different condition
first ,you should know that it  has nothing to do with react-native
[fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) put the data in body to header "payload" when the client made a request.i thought jetty-8.1 does not support get data from the payload header 
,change the way 
[Getting request payload from POST request in Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet) will be helpful
or maybe use the websockt or XMLhttpRequest object to send a request

```
// Read from request
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line);
}
String data = buffer.toString()
```

Comment: Please include relevant code sections from external links into the code body.