# angular send post request but servlet keep showing nul value

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets, post

i have angular controller which triggered with ng-click:

```
    app.controller('showAllWorkersContoller', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("/SafetyManager/workers").success(function(response){
        $scope.workers = response;
        $scope.workerInfo = function(id){
            $http({
                url: '/SafetyManager/workers',
                method: "POST",
                data: { 'ID' : id },
            }).success(function(response){
                    $scope.info = response;
                });
        };
    });
});
```

and when i check on chrome debug it sends in form data: {'ID':"1"} (or any other id num according to the worker i click on)

but when the Servlet get the request:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("post request to Workers (get worker by id )");
    String id = request.getParameter("ID");
    System.out.println("this id is: " + id);


}
```

its print :

```
post request to Workers (get worker by id )

this id is: null
```

how can i get the ID value in the servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you post will not be available as a request parameter, it is in the request body.

You can use a reader to read content from body.

Refer: [Getting request payload from POST request in Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use req.getAttribute(name) to get body content.

Refer this blog:
[Difference between getAttribute() and getParameter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter)

Comment: attribute is not where body content is, go through the SO answer that you have added in your answer..