# Testing post method of java web service

Tags: java

Please anyone give me a clear understanding of why web service with post request cannot be run by putting the url in the browser unlike get method.
I tried running the url in the browser for post method,but it didn't display anything.But when i tried it on SoapUI, I got my desired result.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: coze then u put url into a browser and send it - it will be a GET request? not POST

Answer (score 3):

Because browser send a GET request and your service is expecting a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the difference in a GET and a POST request. POST requests do not use the url to send data. An easy example to understand why this is the case would be a login. You would certainly not want to send your login password in the url.

Comment: So then how to send parameters with the post request.A simple example would be enough to clear my doubt.Thanks.

Comment: An example can be found in this answer: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657510/8596064)

Comment: Good example from client side.Thank you.But how to access this parameters in java rest web service?

Comment: If you are using Spring, try @RequestParam.
If you are using servlets, maybe these answers can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet?rq=1