# Spring MVC - Rest endpoint that receives a List may receive a single object

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 4.3.3 `@RestController` which manages an entity type via `List`s.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("...")
public class EntityRestController {
    @PostMapping
    public void doSomeWork(@RequestBody final List<Entity> entities) { ... }
}
```

I discovered sometimes I may receive a request where the body consists not of an array, but a single JSON object.
I'm using Gson as the default serializer/deserializer and obviously it throws an exception.

```
JSON parse error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

What would the better way to tackle this problem be (at the Controller level)?

Comment: Could you do something alone the lines of habing a different mapping for a SINGLE entity and just executing the other one after converting that one object to a list?

Comment: @zack6849 Unfortunately I cannot control the caller request URL as of now. So I have to work solely on this controller.

Comment: does spring let you overload post mappings so you can have different methods depending on whih mapping it matches?

Comment: @zack6849 Actually you cannot overload a RequestMapping method without modifying its URL. It will throw an "ambiguous mapping" exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HttpServletRequest` in method parameter, like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("...")
public class EntityRestController {
    @PostMapping
    public void doSomeWork(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Do your things here..
    }
}
```

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet) has many answers how to parse request body within HttpServletRequest:

1. Use [apache commons-IO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39792253/554958) : `IOUtils.toString(request.getReader())`.
2. Use [`request.getParameterMap()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587416/554958) :

   ```
   Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();
   for(String paramName : map.keySet()) {
       String[] paramValues = map.get(paramName);

       for(String valueOfParam : paramValues) {
           // Do your things..
       }
   }
   ```

Or other techniques based on your need and preferences.

HTH

Comment: It's going to work for sure, but I'd prefer a cleaner solution if possible.

Comment: You could just accept an `Object` and introspect it to see what the object is a type of then map it within the controller but unless you differentiate the endpoints there isn't really anything cleaner.

Comment: @LppEdd as you mentioned in other comments, other cleaner solution would lead to ambiguous mapping exception. Think on this way: If you think there's a cleaner approach, what object that should be used in the Controller's method parameter?

Comment: A Filter which wraps the HttpServletRequest (and modifies the getReader() method) might be an optimal solution as it can be applied to multiple URL and registered using Java configuration