# Unable to send params in servlet

Tags: java, angularjs, http, servlets

I have angular code

```
app.controller('add', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.msg = "no connect";

        var data = {name:'soso',description:'buba',method:'POST'};

        $http.post(host + "/add-component",data)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.msg = response.data;
            });

    }
});
```

in my servlet, I want to catch it

```
resp.setContentType("application/json; charset = utf8");
String name = req.getParameter("name");
String description = req.getParameter("description");
```

but my name and description both = null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `data` as POST request body, not request parameters. This is documented in [the angular docs for post method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post):

> url   string
>   Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request
>
> data  *
>   Request content

Take a look [at this answer to see how to read request body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14525982/1602555).

These days it's easier to use Spring Boot or other frameworks to handle your server side endpoints. There is nothing wrong with using Servlets but you will have to write more code yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! It realy help for me. <code> Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

        String[] body = req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining()).split("\"");

        for (int i = 1; i < body.length; i += 4) {
            params.put(body[i], body[i + 2]);
        }

        name = params.get("name"); </code>