# Alternative of @ModelAttribute annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Like in `Spring` we have `httpServeletRequest.getParameter("key")` as an alternative to `@RequestParam("key")`, 
do we have any alternative to `@ModelAttribute("key")` ?

```java
model.addAttribute("student",new Student());
...
...
@RequestMapping("/processStudentForm")
public String processTheForm(
    @ModelAttribute("student") Student student
) 
{       
    ...
}
```

Do we have something like?

```java
public String processTheForm(
     Model model
) 
{       
    Student student = model.getAtribute("key");
    ...
}
```

**Update 1**

```java
    @RequestMapping("/showStudentForm")
    public String showTheForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("key",new Student());
        return "studentForm";
    }
```

```html
<form:form action='processStudentForm' modelAttribute='key' method='post'> 
        ... 
</form:form>
```

I am binding the form values into student object. How to access this model attribute through request object??

Comment: There is @RequestBody  annotation in spring-boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The student Model Object cannot be accessed directly though the request object but you can access this in different ways from the request object
.By Default spring does lot of work under the hood its uses FormHttpMessageConverter to convert it to a model map on a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request you can refer the docs.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html

You can do the same what spring does internally.I tried this its working but you can do it in multiple ways refer the stack overflow post for other answers

```
       Map map = httpServletRequest.getParameterMap().entrySet()
            .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> Arrays.stream(e.getValue()).findFirst().get()));
       Student student = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(map, Student.class);
```

[Getting request payload from POST request in Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet)

But its always a good practice to use the default implementation.

Comment: Sir, can you please refer to the update that I have added.